# Bold black line across PDF

Tags: math-mode, errors, pdftex

I have been using latex for several years but I have never had this kind of problem before. Texmaker compiles the tex files correctly but there is a bold black line across the PDF.

What can I do to overcome this issue?

Comment: Could you post a small compete code reproducing your issue?

Comment: This is the problem. I can not understand where the problem is in the code. I divided the code in two parts A and B. I compiled just A and the line disappeared, then I compiled just B and the line disappeared, but when I compile A and B together the line appears.

Comment: No error message?

Comment: No erros, just some warnings. I added a picture to the post.

Comment: are you using the  draft option somewhere?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that was my guess as well, FL what source line corresponds the the formula with the rule, ie which of the warnings you show.

Comment: No, I am not using the draft option. I added a picture with the lines corresponding to the formula. The problem should be between line 387 and line 392. But none of these lines correspond to a warning.

Comment: Please show the full code, not images of code

Comment: The full code is 450 lines. Do you want me to post all of them?

Comment: I already did that. As I said above  I divided the code in two parts A and B. I compiled just A and the line disappeared, then I compiled just B and the line disappeared, but when I compile A and B together the line appears. It does not make sense.

Comment: post the smallest example that you can make that shows the problem.

Comment: I posted the code

Comment: No you need to post something that produces the problem. That is just a fragment not a test document

Comment: Also see [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$` … `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Comment: I got it. The problem was due to this line: \title[\resizebox{6.1in}{!}{---}]{---}. This was producing the black line in the beginning of the third page of the pdf. Anyway, thank you very much to you all for the help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the original problem has been solved in comments and the question as edited has no statement of the  problem.